# MySql PHP Update Error

Tags: php, mysql, insert-update

I've been messing about with this code for a few hours now and can't work out why it's not working.  It's a profile update php page that is passed through JQuery and all seems to be fine except for it actually updating into the table.  Here is the code I'm using:

```
session_start();
include("db-connect.php");//Contains $con

$get_user_sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = '$user_username'";
$get_user_res = mysqli_query($con, $get_user_sql);
while($user = mysqli_fetch_array($get_user_res)){
    $user_id = $user['id'];
}
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_REQUEST["name"]);
$location = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_REQUEST["location"]);
$about = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_REQUEST["about"]);

$insert_member_sql = "UPDATE profile_members SET id = '$user_id', names = '$name', location = '$location', about = '$about' WHERE id = '$user_id'"; 
$insert_member_res = mysqli_query($con, $insert_member_sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)>0){
echo "1";
}else{
echo "0";
}
```

All I get as the return value is 0, can anybody spot any potential mistakes? Thanks

Comment: return value from what? whats the error?

Comment: Did you verify it on the database side?

Comment: It's not running the UPDATE into the database and returning the value of affected rows

Comment: Not that it's your problem, but no reason to update the id field to user_id where the id field is equal to user_id...

Comment: Where does `$user_username` get its value?

Comment: @mofolo Gets it from a session started on a previous page - I know that part works though

Comment: Can you show us the structure of `profile_members`?  `mysql> Describe profile_members;` ?

Comment: Profile_members simply has 4 columns (id, names, location, about)

Comment: change this code: if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)>0){
echo "1";
}else{
echo "0";
}, into if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)>0){
echo $insert_member_sql;
}else{
echo $insert_member_sql;
}

Comment: Just to see if the query is well formed ,)

Comment: It's definitely something wrong with the line UPDATE - I've just edited the script to INSERT INTO and it works fine - Can anyone see a reason why UPDATE isn't working?

Comment: It's pointless to add id, and are you sure 'names' isn't suppose to be 'name' ?

Comment: No, I know the problem now, it's because the row doesn't exist to start with, now it exists it is updating.  Thing is I need it to add and also update - Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: You need two separate action to do that. Take a look at my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Jonast92, I'll look at using that script later but for now I just really want to update & insert with the code I have - I'm sure I read somewhere that there was a statement which inserted if the row didn't exist but updated if it did?

Comment: No problem, That's actually easy; SELECT from the database and look for the user, if you find the user, then you update, if it returns false (It doesn't exist), then you insert.

Comment: Good thinking, Thanks @Jonast92

Comment: You're welcome, feel free to vote up the comment if It's useful to you, it might be useful to others. I also highly recommend to take a look at the script that I posted :)

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, use

```
require("db-connect.php");
```

instead of

```
include("db-connect.php");
```

And now, consider using prepared statements, your code is vulnerable to sql injections.

Consider using PDO instead of the mysql syntax, in the long run I find it much better to use and it avoids a lot of non-sense-making problems, you can do it like this (You can keep it in the db-connect file if you want, and even make the database conncetion become global):

```
// Usage:   $db = connectToDatabase($dbHost, $dbName, $dbUsername, $dbPassword);
// Pre:     $dbHost is the database hostname, 
//          $dbName is the name of the database itself,
//          $dbUsername is the username to access the database,
//          $dbPassword is the password for the user of the database.
// Post:    $db is an PDO connection to the database, based on the input parameters.
function connectToDatabase($dbHost, $dbName, $dbUsername, $dbPassword)
{
    try
    {
        return new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$dbName;charset=UTF-8", $dbUsername, $dbPassword);
    }
    catch(PDOException $PDOexception)
    {
        exit("<p>An error ocurred: Can't connect to database. </p><p>More preciesly: ". $PDOexception->getMessage(). "</p>");
    }
}
```

And then init the variables:

```
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$databaseName = 'databaseName';
$pass = '';
```

Now you can access your database via

```
$db = connectToDatabase($host, $databaseName, $user, $pass);
```

Now, here's how you can solve your problem (Using prepared statements, avoiding sql injection):

```
function userId($db, $user_username)
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = :username;";
    $statement = $db->prepare($query); // Prepare the query.
    $statement->execute(array(
        ':username' => $user_username
    ));
    $result = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if($result)
    {
        return $result['user_id'];
    }
    return false
}

function updateProfile($db, $userId, $name, $location, $about)
{
    $query = "UPDATE profile_members SET name = :name, location = :location, about = :about WHERE id = :userId;";
    $statement = $db->prepare($query); // Prepare the query.
    $result = $statement->execute(array(
        ':userId' => $userId,
        ':name' => $name,
        ':location' => $location,
        ':about' => $about
    ));
    if($result)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false
}

$userId = userId($db, $user_username); // Consider if it is not false.

$name = $_REQUEST["name"];
$location = $_REQUEST["location"];
$about = $_REQUEST["about"];

$updated = updateProfile($db, $userId, $name, $location, $about);
```

You should check the queries though, I fixed them a little bit but not 100% sure if they work.

You can easily make another function which inserts into tha database, instead of updating it, or keeping it in the same function; if you find an existance of the entry, then you insert it, otherwise you update it.

Comment: Regarding your last point, although prepared statements cannot be over-praised (use them!), the MySQLi functions aren't deprecated, unlike the mysql_query() functions, in fact along with PDO they're one of the successors.

Comment: That's true, but using PDO solves a lot of problems and is in the long run not as painful to use ad mysqli.